# Resource files for different clients

Tags: c#, resources

I have an issue with being able to be client specific with my word resource files.

I have a default file  WordResources.resx,  and language specific resources e.g.   WordResources.en-GB.resx, WordResources.fr.resx.

How do I go about having client specific resource files, for example;
WordResources.client1.resx, WordResources.client2.resx.

Depending on the compile e.g. client1 will build with WordResources.client1.resx but will replace the default resource file?

I was hoping I could have different client specific resource files for only a few word differences and then keep the default file and use any language in conjunction with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could build several releases. We typically rename the resx files during build and build for each client a own setup/release.

You could do this in the pre-build event of your projects and could switch on a environment variable.

Comment: I've decided to go with the below approach. It will be a slow migration to the new method but will change it per client request.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve my issue with the bespoke client files. It will take a while to migrate to the new method of resolving the string for localisation but will be achieved per change request.

I have defined a global application setting in the database that specifies the client.

The client name is then used to find the appropriately named .resx file and failing it can't find the string in the .resx file it will default to either the specified culture version or read from the default resource file / specified default culture resx and failing all of this, returns the passed string.

```
public static string GetLocalizedString(string text)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(LocalizationExtensions));
    cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Cache["Culture"].ToString());
    string clientName = HttpContext.Current.Cache["ClientName"].ToString();       
    return    (new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources." + clientName + "." + clientName, assembly)).GetString(text, cultureInfo) 
           ?? (new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.WordResources", assembly)).GetString(text, cultureInfo) 
           ?? text;
}
```

The application setting for the client name is loaded in the cache.